# Maximize browser window size in webdriver-io

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Is there a counterpart to the *browser.windowHandleMaximize* command in webdriver-io **v7**?

In v7 this command throws an error:

```
TypeError: browser.windowHandleMaximize is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await browser.maximizeWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver/#maximizewindow

There is not method as you mentioned , use maximizewindow

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This command is an error "Error: Command "maximizeWindow" is not yet implemented"